# IntelliJ IDEA create patch from difference

Tags: git, intellij-idea, diff

I have IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2018.2.3.
I am trying to create a patch from a difference (Compare with...) in IDE, but I can not find a button to do so. I have several commits on branch_A already. I do not need to create a patch from local changes, I need to create the patch from difference with another branch.

In git it simple `git diff branch_A branch_B >> diff.patch`

Is there any way to achieve it in the IDE?

Comment: Under Version control window --> Local changes --> right click on the changes --> create patch is that what you after?

Comment: It's not local changes. I have several commits on my branch already. I want to apply patch, wich contains all changes, comparing another branch

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2 I was able to make it like this:

0. Make sure you have no current local changes beforehand: commit them or put them to stash.
1. VCS -> Git -> Branches -> [select branch to compare with] -> Show Diff with Working Tree
2. [in opened difference view select needed files] -> [right mouse button] -> Get from Branch
3. VCS -> Create Patch from Local Changes...

Comment: But it will be much more comfortable to make a patch in one click in the Show diff window. Without using local changes

Comment: I tried this approach, but new files are not included in the patch

Answer (score 2):

Merge your branch with changes to source branch using VCS -> Git -> Merge changes with **Squash commit** option. After merge no commit will be done, but you will see changes in a single Changelist. You can click on this Changelist with right mouse button and select *Create Patch from local changes* option to export patch file. Then you can just revert.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a patch in the commit changes dialog.
1. go to local changes in version control and press `ctrl+k` to invoke commit dialog
2. fill in the required fields and then instead of pressing the commit button there is a dropdown arrow next to commit that you can select to create a patch.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/commit-and-push-changes.html#invoke-commit-dialog

Comment: I do not want to create patch from non-commited files. I have several commits in my branch already.

Comment: My bad didn't read that properly don't know how I missed it. I don't have experience creating patches from previously commited work.  Here is a link which describes the process https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/use-patches.html

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it on IntelliJ 2020.1.3

1. Commit all you work in your current branch (say, `my-committed-branch`)
2. Check out the branch against which you want to generate the diff as a patch (say, master)
3. Create a new branch from the base i.e. master as say `my-uncommitted-branch`
4. Go to VCS -> Git -> Checkout files from branch and choose `my-committed-branch`. It will show the list of files you have changed. Select all and click ok. You will now have all your changes as uncommitted changes
5. Now select VCS -> Create Patch from local changes

Comment: this requires the plugin https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10795-git-checkout-files-from-branch  .... but it works only with NEW files, not with MODIFIED files...